# Angular8, ASP.NET Core Api , OpenIdConnect & IdentityServer4 my NG app cannot obtain a /.well-known(...) document cannot obtain even an ErrorMessage

Tags: openid-connect

I'm completely new to the IdentityServer 4 & OpenIdConnect, 
I've got such an app, where the authentication & authorization mechanics are implemented according to FullStackMark's tutorial here: https://fullstackmark.com/post/21/user-authentication-and-identity-with-angular-aspnet-core-and-identityserver
And I got already to the step, when I have a problem with logging my client in using Implicit flow; I can succesfully register a new user in my MsSql local Db, but when I am trying to log in there a weird error occurs: when I am invoking the `oidc-client` library UserManager's method `signinRedirect()` function I am receiving `zone.js:3372 GET http://localhost:5000/.well-known/openid-configuration 500 (Internal Server Error)` with a full stack trace, and when I dug in the debugger, i saw an interesting `TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them` message... 
Worth to mention, what it is obviously a "public" endpoint; I mean, I can open this discovery document without any problems or mistakes with Postman, browser or anything.

I went completely insane looking for a cause of that problem... What may be the most possible mistakes that I'd have done? 
Plus, of course, What bits of my code may point a solution for that problem?

Comment: Okay, I dug in to receive the `application-error: Invalid object name 'Clients'.` in my responseHeaders when 500 occurs. 
I'll have a look, what might cause it

Comment: Okay, Now I kno, what it's `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: Invalid object name 'Clients'.` maybe some extra migration will do?

Comment: It has not solved the problem... But as long as I can dig in, I am receiving an error `Invalid Object Name: 'Client` and the path of it is pointed to : `/.well-known/openid-connect`

Comment: Problem Solved already.

Comment: For me the response for the openId is getting late, Do you know how to reslove this issue. I need it within 2sec